# WP7 controls: When to set VisualState after recovering from Tombstone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, visualstatemanager, tombstoning

**My question is simple: WHEN** (on what event?) can I be sure that a control has fully loaded and has its states and templates also?

**Why am I asking:**

I'm trying to restore the state of my own WP7 control after recovering from tombstone. This control looks like a calendar in a weekly view. In this calendar you can select many items displayed as colored Rectangles.

If I select any of them, and then go to tombstone and come back to the page, it seems like my control forgot which `Rectangles` were selected. In fact, it did NOT forget the data itself, but the `Rectangles` forgot their selected state.

After recovering from tombstone, I try to select the `Rectangles` by setting their `VisualState` to "Selected" (which works in any other scenario). I found out, that it fails, because `VisualStateManager` can't find the `"Selected"` state.

I know this is tricky, because when coming back from tombstone the controls do not build exactly as in any "normal" case. (for example `Bindings` and `Templates` do not apply in the same order) But up until now I could always trust, that when `FrameworkElement.Loaded` fired, I had my controls ready. Now it seems like `VisualState` is not. (I tried to set the state from `Loaded` event handler, but results are the same, `VisualStateManager.GoToState` returns with `false`.)

What more can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one! I have also experienced issues where UI events fire before the UI itself is fully constructed, see [this blog post for an example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/06/metro-in-motion-8-autocompletebox-reveal-animation/). My general approach to this is to handle the `LayoutUpdated` event, which fires each time the visual tree is updated. You will find that this event fires multiple times, both before and after the `Loaded` event.

When the `Layoutupdated` event fires, you can check whether the visual state change has worked, if so, no longer handle the event. If not, keep trying!

Within your loaded event, try the following:

```
 // try to set the state
  if (VisualStateManager.GoToState(myControl, "myState") == false)
  {
    // if failed, wait for the next LayoutUpdated event
    EventHandler updateHandler = null;
    updateHandler = (s, e2) =>
    {
      if (VisualStateManager.GoToState(myControl, "myState") == false) 
      {
        myControl.LayoutUpdated -= updateHandler;
      }
    };
    myControl.LayoutUpdated += updateHandler;
  }
```

Comment: Hah! Thanks a million!
The structure of my controls have changed since yesterday, but the method works! :) Thanks again!